# How to write or read powers (math) by words?

Tags: mathematics, reading-aloud

What's the way to write or to read power (math) it in words?

Does "powered by" is correct?

For example: 
"2 powered by 5 divided by 2 **powered by** 3." works?

Also "What 4 **powered by** 3 does equal to?" is correct?

[image]

[image]

Comment: FWIW, the operation is normally (AFAIK) called "exponentiation".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is usual to say

> "2 **raised to the power** 5"

or more concisely

> "2 **to the power** 5"

"2 to the power **of** 5" is also acceptable, but not "2 *powered by* 5".

Amongst mathematicians **"2 to the 5"** is shorthand, "**power of**" being understood.
So you should say

> "*2 to the power 5 divided by 2 to the power 3*"

and

> "*What is 4 to the power 3 equal to?*"

Comment: it may be worth pointing out whether "two to the 5" is spoken as "two to the five" or "two to the fifth". some languages, german is an example, do use the ordinal instead of the cardinal here.

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that "squared" and "cubed" are commonly used for exponents of 2 and 3 respectively.

Comment: @dlatikay Maybe in German, but English mathematicians would interpret _two to the fifth_ as 2 raised to the power one fifth (1/5) which is the  fifth root of 2. something completely different.

Comment: @PeterJennings However, it's pretty common (at least in AmE) to use xto the nth power' instead of 'x raised to the power of n'.

Comment: I'll disagree with Peter Jennings on this- $2^{5}$ would commonly be read in English as "two to the fifth" or "two to the fifth power."  You would read $2^{(1/5}}$ as "two to the one fifth"

Comment: @BrianBorchers On second thoughts you are correct, I was wrong. "**two to the fifth**" and "**two to the power five**" are both 2^5. "two to the **one** fifth" is 2^(1/5)